# Angular 9 can't make a post request

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9

I'm currentry just a begginner in Angular,

I'm trying make a post request using this function:

```
 signIn(user: User) {
    console.log("1");
    return this.http
      .post<any>(`${this.endpoint}/login`, user)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log("2");
        localStorage.setItem("access_token", res.token);
        this.getUserProfile(res._id).subscribe(res => {
          this.currentUser = res;
          this.router.navigate(["user-profile/" + res.msg._id]);
        });
      });
  }
```

I tried to monitor the network (using the network tab in firefox), and I've found out that no data is sent.

When opening the console it displays "1" but not "2".

Thank you

Comment: can you show screenshot of request in network tab?/

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the observable and subscribe to it there. Now you are returning a subscription so you might not know when actually the call is triggered. Also try to avoid nested subscriptions. You could use RxJS higher order operators (like [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap)) to pipe multiple observables. Try the following

some service

```js
signIn(user: User) : Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<any>(`${this.endpoint}/login`, user).pipe(
    switchMap((user) => {
      localStorage.setItem("access_token", user.token);
      return this.getUserProfile(user._id);
    }
  );
}
```

component

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.someService.signIn(user).subscribe(
    res => {
      this.currentUser = res;
      this.router.navigate(["user-profile/" + res.msg._id]);
    },
    (error) => {
      // always good practice to handle HTTP observable errors
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but it doesn't seem to work, maybe the problem comes from elsewhere

Comment: You could check if the end-point is correct in the function `getUserProfile()`.